# Finding text using selenium

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Thanks for your assistance I have been scratching my head and Googling all articles. Basically I want to extract the REQ ID and put it in an Excel sheet The REQ ID always starts with REQ and 6 zeros. Anyway I can do this either using Xpath find text?
Unfortunately the code below results in a null value as a number of elements share the same "class".
Ideally it would try to find the text "REQ000000" on the page. If found it would give me the contents of the tag or select the entire REQ00000012345.

```
<p _ngcontent-tme-c63="" class="headline-item__description font-weight-light text-secondary ng-star-inserted"> REQ00000012345 <!----></p>



 Sub GetReqID()
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Dim Applicant, act As String
Dim answer, answer1, i As Integer
Dim d As WebDriver
Set d = New ChromeDriver
Dim keys As New Selenium.keys
Dim url As String
url = "https://url.com"

With d
.Start "Chrome"
.Get url
.Window.Maximize
'Wait 3 seconds
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
'Login

d.FindElementById("user_lg").SendKeys "username"
d.FindElementById("login_user_pwd").SendKeys "password"
d.FindElementById("login-btn").Click

'After logging in present dialog
answer = MsgBox("Get REQ# for " & Applicant, vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Procced")

If answer = vbYes Then
Dim REQ As String
REQ = d.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@class, '" + "headline-item__description font-weight-light text-secondary ng-star-inserted" + "')]").Text
    MsgBox REQ
End If

End With

answer1 = MsgBox("Have you clicked Submit for " & Applicant, vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Procced")

If answer1 = vbYes Then
    d.Quit
Else
    MsgBox "Close the file to end session", vbCritical, "Not Done?"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I managed this was to extract all the  tags into the Excel sheet. The subroutine stops when it finds the REQ000000.